# How to list local npm package contents

Tags: node.js, npm

I need to list all files that would be included by `npm pack` command for a local(unpublished) package, but without doing the packing in the first place.

I guess this is the same list of files that would be used by `npm publish` as well.
Basically, everything in my package folder except `node_modules` and `.npmignore` files.

Comment: Looking at the docs from `npm publish`, `npm pack` is the 'dry run' for `npm publish`.  Maybe it would help someone answer your question if you explain _why_ you don't want to use `npm pack`?  Just thinking out loud.

Comment: My goal is to deploy the project to some other location on the same machine, from where it will run as a `systemd` service. So I `pack` just to `untar` it in the new location. I just want to get the list of files and copy them directly.

Answer (score 1):

It might make more sense to simply copy the files over, ignoring anything you don't want according to the same rules that `npm publish` would use.

From the docs on`publish`:

> All files in the package directory are included if no local .gitignore
>   or .npmignore file exists. If both files exist and a file is ignored
>   by .gitignore but not by .npmignore then it will be included.

The assumption you put in your question about which files are used and which are not seems correct.

In short, I don't believe NPM has such a command, but you could probably author a bash script to do this without much trouble.

Comment: Yes, it's kind of a deal breaker, and also I wanted to not have any other 3rd-party dependency if possible. Just using npm.

Comment: This was the whole point, to avoid compiling this list myself, to not reinvent the wheel. I tried also to see if npm can install directly from one location to another, but no luck.

Comment: Right.  I think for the moment you might have to work outside of NPM to get it done.  Not the answer you wanted, but I think that's the case.